# Packet manipulation library in C

Tags: c, packet

I am playing with [libnetfilter_queue](http://www.netfilter.org/projects/libnetfilter_queue/index.html) and am looking for a good C library to work with packets captured by libnetfilter_queue. I really like the [dpkt](http://code.google.com/p/dpkt/) library for python and some similar library for C would be wonderful.

Any other workaround or example code for manipulating the packets are also welcome.

with regards,

raj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Netfilter's TPROXY target is available (even at *BSD) => setsockopt can be done from your python code without messing at C.